# Counting chessboard rectangles

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, puzzle, chessboard

I am looking into the puzzle count the number of rectangles in a regular $8*8$ chessboard.
For a 1 by 1 chessboard there are 0 rectangles
For a 2 by 2 chessboard there are 4 rectangles (2 by 1)
For a 3 by 3 chessboard there are 6 rectangles of 1 by 2, 3 rectangles of 1 by 3, 6 rectangles of 2 by 1 and 3 rectangles of 3 by 1 i.e. total 22
For a 4 by 4 rectangles there are 56 rectangles in total (12 of 1 by 2, 12 of 2 by 1, 8 of 2 by 4, 8 of 4 by 2, 4 of 1 by 4, 4 of 4 by 1, 2 of 2 by 4, 2 of 4 by 2, 2 of 3 by 4, 2 of 4 by 3).
So we have the following sequence (4, 22, 56, ...):

| 2 $\times$ 2 | 3 $\times$ 3 | 4 $\times$ 4 | 5 $\times$ 5 | 6 $\times$ 6 | 7 $\times$ 7 | 8 $\times$ 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 22 | 56 |  |  |  |  |

I can't see a pattern in the sequence. Is there one that I am missing?

Comment: In the preview the table looks ok

Comment: I thought this syntax for the tables should work https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Does it help to insert an empty line before (and after) the table?

Comment: @MartinR: That worked!

Comment: What exactly counts as a rectangle? What about 1x1 rectangles? Or 2x2, 2x3, 3x3 on the 3 by 3 board? Etc ...

Comment: @MartinR: The way I interpreted/understood the puzzle is to not consider squares (are we generally count them by default as a rectangle)?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A052149

Answer (score 2):

Counting all rectangles (i.e. including squares) can be done be first choosing the horizontal lines at top and bottom of the rectangle. This can be done in   $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\2\\\end{pmatrix}$ ways.

The same is true for the vertical lines. So the total is $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\2\\\end{pmatrix}^2.$

If you want to exclude squares then you can find them separately and subtract from the total.

Comment: `first choosing the horizontal lines at top and bottom of the rectangle` what do you mean by this?

Comment: A rectangle has a top and a bottom edge. There are $n+1$ possibilities for these two lines ranging from $0$, bottom line, to $n$, top line.

Comment: By multiplying i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\2\\\end{pmatrix}^2.$ aren't we including invalid configurations? I.e. 2 lines on the left with vertical lines on the right that don't form a shape?

Comment: The combinations formula is for a choice of two different lines.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\2\\\end{pmatrix}$ is all possible choices of 2 horizontal lines from the 9 right? The same for vertical. What I don't get is how will the multiplication not include invalid combinations. Would it be possible to elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: `If you want to exclude squares then you can find them separately` how?

Comment: Q1. Try drawing two horizontal and two vertical lines as suggested. they will always determine a valid rectangle.

Comment: Q2. You might prefer to find these by your original method since there is a simple pattern for these. The number of 1 by 1 is $n^2$. The number of 2 by 2 is $(n-1)^2$. etc.

Comment: How is counting the squares similar? you get the same $\binom{n+1}{2}$ for the horizontal lines, but for the vertical lines now the distance between the vertices is fixed; we could try  $2\binom{n+1}{1}$, that is, choosing one vertex determines 2 squares (since the lenght were already fixed by the horizontal lines choice), one to the left and one to the right, but there are border issues.

Comment: I've added the method I think is preferable in the comments.